# How to change a ListView Item as Marked In React-Native

Tags: react-native

I am using a `ListView` as a selector, everything is working but I cannot change the visual state of the element of the list:

```
this.state = {
  dataSource: dataSource.cloneWithRows([
                        {
                            provincia:"Bocas del Toro",
                            capital: "Bocas del Toro", 
                            selected:false,
                        },
                        {
                            provincia:"Coclé",
                            capital: "Penonomé", 
                            selected:false,
                        },
...
```

I change the data directly onPress like this:

```
rowPressed(rowData) {
    rowData.selected = true;
    this.props.onAreaSelect(rowData);
}
```

And I try to change the view like this:

```
<TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this.rowPressed(rowData)}
      underlayColor='#eeeeee' >
    <View>
      <View style={[styles.rowContainer, this.state.selected ? styles.selected :  styles.unselected ]}>
        <View  style={styles.textContainer}>
            <Text style={styles.title} 
                  numberOfLines={1}>{rowData.provincia}</Text>
            <Text style={styles.description} 
                  numberOfLines={1}>Capital: {rowData.capital}</Text>
        </View>

      </View>
      <View style={styles.separator} />
    </View>
  </TouchableHighlight>
```

Where `styles.selected` and `styles.unselected` are just 2 different defined styles.

Comment: in the onPress, why do we have to use `onPress={() => this.rowPressed(rowData)}`?  In other views where the `TouchableHighlight` is not in a ListView, I can just use `onPress={this.rowPressed(rowData)}`, but why here I have to add the extra `() =>`?

Answer (score 3):

I can't tell what your `onAreaSelect` does here, but I had the similar issue, and the trick is to set `dataSource` state again corresponding to your changed rowData.

```
this.setState({
  dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(
    // your new data here
  )   
});
```

For detailed implementation, React Native official ListView example did help me.
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/listview.html#examples

In their example, they use another object `_pressData` to store which row is being selected, and every time it's changed, they call `_genRows` to do the above.

Comment: in the onPress, why do we have to use `onPress={() => this.rowPressed(rowData)}`?  In other views where the `TouchableHighlight` is not in a ListView, I can just use `onPress={this.rowPressed(rowData)}`, but why here I have to add the extra `() =>`?

Comment: the reason why you add extra () => is because you want to pass a function that would be run onPress rather than just call it during rendering. If you don't add it, while it is being rendered it will be called straight away rather than only onPress.