# React Native Listview selected styling

Tags: javascript, listview, reactjs, react-native

### What I have

I have a listview in react native that is hydrating from firebase. I display this listview, and when I touch the desired row, it sends the data back to the parent where I then save and manipulate the data in other ways, so that's all working.

### My Goal

I want more interactivity with the end users. When a user touches the desired row, I want the row to show a checkmark. When they touch a different row, I want the checkmark to be on that particular row.

### My Question

How do I go about creating this feature? It's very similar to radio buttons in web, but in React Native I haven't seen a feature like that yet. Right now, I can display the list and then touch a desired row and it will show a icon for that particular row. However, it will not go back to its original state after selecting it again.

### My Code

*Rendering the list.js*

```
<TouchableHighlight onPress={ ()=> this.combine(this.props.title)}>
<View style={styles.settingsWrapper}>

    <View style={styles.settingsName}>
        <Text style={styles.settingsTitle}>{this.props.title}</Text>
    </View>
    <View style={styles.settingsImage}>

        <Icon name={this.setStyle(this.props.title)} style={{fontSize:30, color: '#2ecc71'}}></Icon>



    </View>

</View>
</TouchableHighlight>
```

*setStyle function*

```
  setStyle: function(medName) {

  if (this.state.selectedMed == this.props.title) {
      return 'cab'
  } else {
      return 'check'
  }
},
```

*combine function*

```
  combine:function(selectedMedication){
this.props.callback(selectedMedication);
this.setState({
  selectedMed:selectedMedication
})
},
```

I've been banging my head against this for a long time. Any help or ideas would be greatly valued.

Comment: Could you provide a bit more code for context? I see you are using this.state.selectedMed but I have no idea where that is being set or used other then in the setStyle function. In addition what is this.combine doing? Showing the whole component could be very helpful in finding the right answer.

Comment: I added my combine function to the question. Also, I initialize 'this.state.selectedMed' in my *getInitialState()* method. I just set it to a empty string.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is you need to re-render your entire data source for the list view. Unfortunately just simply updating the state of the component doesn't make the list view re-evaluate the rows therein. See the following for a bit more info:

[How to change a ListView Item as Marked In React-Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29520910/how-to-change-a-listview-item-as-marked-in-react-native)