# React-Native: ListView highlight row when selected

Tags: react-native, react-native-listview

I want to create a ListView that when a row is selecteced the row is hightlighted untill it is selected again. I have been working with ListView example from the [reac-native documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/listview.html)
and various other tutorials but I am getting no where.

A working example or even the methods that I should be using to point me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

I am new to React-Native if it isn't already obvious.

Comment: Have you tried building this yet?

Comment: Yes I have. I am working from the example from the documentation. I am not sure which methods to call, for example: TouchableWithoutFeedback, TouchableOpacity, TouchableHighlight. I find the explanations on the documentation unclear and unhelpful.

Comment: TouchableWithoutFeedback - Something that can touch but doesn't change its look when you do.
TouchableOpacity - Lower the opacity of the view while touched.
TouchableHighlight - Raise the brightness of the view while touched.

Comment: TouchableHighlight sounds like what I need except I need the row to stay highlighted untill it is selected again.

Comment: Hint, you need an array to store the row indexes clicked :)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38388623/react-native-listview-selected-styling/38435298#38435298

Comment: It's very easy, set State for view and done.

Answer (score 0):

*you can use `underlay` property of `TouchableHighlight` react-native component.*

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
     StyleSheet,
     Text,
     View,
     ListView,
     TouchableHighlight
} from 'react-native';

class helloRN extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    const ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});
    this.state = {
      dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(['row 1', 'row 2', 'row 3', 'row 4', 'row 5', 'row 6', 'row 7', 'row 8', 'row 9', 'row 10']),
    };
  }

  _onPressButton() {
    console.log("On Press")
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ListView style = {styles.container}
        dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
        renderRow={
          (rowData) => <TouchableHighlight style = {styles.rowStyle} underlayColor = '#008b8b' onPress = {this._onPressButton}>
                          <Text style = {styles.rowText}>{rowData}</Text>
                       </TouchableHighlight>
        }
      />
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
    },
    rowText: {
        fontSize: 20,
        textAlign: 'center',
        color: '#FFFFFF'
    },
    rowStyle: {
        backgroundColor: '#333333',
        flex: 1,
        height: 100,
        margin: 2,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
    },
});

module.exports = helloRN
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: this is not working. on press event not even triggered.

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me once I added ***export default*** in front of class and removed the *module.exports* statement at the bottom. The code looks as follows. Hope this works for everyone like it did for me.

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import {
        StyleSheet,
        Text,
        View,
        ListView,
        TouchableHighlight
    } from 'react-native';

    export default class helloRN extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        const ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});
        this.state = {
        dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(['row 1', 'row 2', 'row 3', 'row 4', 'row 5', 'row 6', 'row 7', 'row 8', 'row 9', 'row 10']),
        };
    }

    _onPressButton() {
        console.log("On Press")
    }

    render() {
        return (
        <ListView style = {styles.container}
            dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
            renderRow={
            (rowData) => <TouchableHighlight style = {styles.rowStyle} underlayColor = '#008b8b' onPress = {this._onPressButton}>
                            <Text style = {styles.rowText}>{rowData}</Text>
                        </TouchableHighlight>
            }
        />
        );
    }
    }

    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
        container: {
            flex: 1,
            backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
        },
        rowText: {
            fontSize: 20,
            textAlign: 'center',
            color: '#FFFFFF'
        },
        rowStyle: {
            backgroundColor: '#333333',
            flex: 1,
            height: 100,
            margin: 2,
            justifyContent: 'center',
            alignItems: 'center',
        },
    });
```